# create webView programmatically in android (without using xml)

Tags: layout, webview, runtime

I want to create WebView programmatically without using xml files. I have used this :

```
LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 
        view.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 
        WebView web=new WebView(this);
        web.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
        view.addView(web);
```

I have also added internet permission in manifest file. But nothing is happening no webView is there when i launch the application. Please help.

Comment: You should post your entire code. the issue can be at adding your linear layout into Activity but you must post all of your java and xml code in order to be sure of that.

Comment: little late, wasn't even a member that time but you linear layout is not even the current layout of the activity so either add it or find a root from xml